# Php how to send over to a page with similar word

Tags: php, html, mysql

I started learning how to code a few weeks ago and I have been stuck on this problem for a while.I will try my best to explain this.

I have a gallery of ingredient names and every time i click on them it redirects me to a page where there is info on them and cuisine with that ingredient which is from the 2nd database.
Ex if i click on almonds it redirects me to the page with descriptions and cuisine from 2nd database that uses it.
My problem is if on the 2nd database i put in 2 pounds of almonds is there a way to ignore the 2 pounds and only pick up the keyword almonds.

I think its the where is the problem because it has to be specific to show up but im not certain.Hope you guys can help me out thanks

```
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){

  $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

  $query_fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = 
  $id");

     while($show = mysqli_fetch_array($query_fetch)){
     $query_fetch2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM cuisine WHERE 
            ingredient_1= '".$show['image_text']."'
         OR ingredient_2='".$show['image_text']."'
         OR ingredient_3='".$show['image_text']."'
         OR ingredient_4='".$show['image_text']."'
         OR ingredient_5='".$show['image_text']."'
            ");

    echo " 
        <div class='container'style='background-
       color:".$show['frame_color'].";'>
        <div class='titletxt'>".$show['image_text']."</div>

        <div class='imgcontainer'><div class='crop'><img class='img1' 
        src='".$show['image'].".jpg'></div>
        <div class='crop'><img class='img1' src='".$show['image2'].".jpg'>
        </div><div class='txt'>".$show['text']."</div><br></div>
        </div>
        </div>";


      }

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by second database? You should have one database and multiple tables. Right?

Comment: Since you're learning, I suggest you learn in the way `PDO` https://phpdelusions.net/pdo with Placeholders instead of `mysqli_` to make your Future easier.

Comment: I have one with multiples for the ingredients and another for the cuisine

Comment: _and_ read about database normalization. When you start numbering your field names, then there is something wrong!

Comment: Yeah I agree with @Jeff you should really familiarize yourself with the Database Normalization techniques. They will make your life easier when you design Database systems. You'd be able to do something like this: `"SELECT * FROM images JOIN cuisine ON images.cuisine_id = cuisine.id WHERE images.image_id = $id"` with a better design. Check it out! http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/normalization

Comment: My guess is: you have "2 pounds" in the field "ingredient_1". That shouldn't be there. Have a seperate field for the amount used! (and may be another one for the unit)

Comment: alright i will try that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LIKE` should solve your problem. Just need to add % to search the keyword you need.

When you want random string at front (E.g in your case is *2 pound*), you need to put % at front. But when you want the random text at behind, you need to put behind.

```
$query_fetch2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM cuisine WHERE 
            ingredient_1 LIKE '%".$show['image_text']."%'
        AND ingredient_2 LIKE '%".$show['image_text']."%'
         ...
            ");
```

More detail of how to use `LIKE`

Please refer here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: @chingdonh please vote it up if you find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `like` operator. something like this

```
 $query_fetch = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * from cuisines where ingredients LIKE '%'" . $_GET['yourEnteredIngredient'] . "'%'");
```

More lessons about [like operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: __please__ add a warning about sql-injection! Using direct user input in an sql statement...

Answer (score 0):

You have a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.
Your actual problem is your database structure, which leads you to have a string to search for, where the ingredient should be unique in this case. Keeping it that way will lead you to other problems.
For example imagine one of your ingrediences is "filet". You then might have a "fish filet", a "chicken breast filet", ...
The following will not answer your question, but I'm trying to give you a hint what your database structure *should* look like to be safe for the future:

```
| TABLE cuisines
| -------
| id
| label
| recipe
| otherfields...


| TABLE ingredients
| -----------
| id
| label
| unit
| image (points to table images with id)
| nutritionInfo
| supplier
| ....whatever

| TABLE ingredient2Cousine
| ------------------
| ingredient (id)
| cuisine (id)
| amount
```

Now you can easily query for all cousines that have that ingredient used.